# Reanchor keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I somehow caused my android keyboard to float on the screen, and also to be a bit smaller, instead of being anchored at the bottom.  How do I anchor it again?  Thanks

Comment: What keyboard are you using, and on what device? I can't envision a tear-away keyboard on a phone, so probably a tablet.

Comment: Samsung S7 using android operating system.  I now know the answer:  Press the microphone icon and then the keyboard icon that appears.